# Angular 4 select initial value not selecting correctly when used with objects

Tags: angular, select

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qbJZCMSpBevlpGeZlcaf):

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
    <option 
      *ngFor="let item of items" 
      [attr.selected]="item.Id == selectedValue.Id ? '' : null" 
      [ngValue]="item" >
        {{item.Text}}
    </option>
  </select>

export class App {
      selectedValue: DataItem = {Id: 2, Text: 'two'};
      items: DataItem[] = [{Id: 1, Text: 'one'}, {Id: 2, Text: 'two'}, {Id: 3, Text: 'three'}]]; }

export class DataItem{
  Id: number;
  Text: string;
}
```

Tried many suggestions from various google and stackoverflow answers, but could not get it working. Anyone has a solution? I'm not interested in a solution which suggests NOT to use ngModel or handle change events.

Comment: [compareWith] works like a charm! Somehow did not find post you have referenced. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! Glad to hear it worked! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"` to `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue.Id"` and

`[ngValue]="item"` to `[ngValue]="item.Id"`

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue.Id">
    <option 
      *ngFor="let item of items" 
      [attr.selected]="item.Id == selectedValue.Id ? '' : null" 
      [ngValue]="item.Id" >
        {{item.Text}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

or try this

```
 <select  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue.Id">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.Id">
            {{item.Text}}
    </option>
</select>
```